# Widgets Style attributes at run time in android

Tags: android, android-widget

Is thera any way one can define style attributes in XML file and apply them to widgets created at run time.

Attributes

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#0000ff"
android:typeface="serif"   
android:textSize="15sp"
```

And i am creating a button to which i want to apply these

```
Button b = new Button(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good application explained in detail way [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html). This example using a style to set for its own widget.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Can u specify any other method?

Comment: Can I know what is the problem that method?

Comment: Hmm .. its necessary for my application to set the text font to Serif .. Had it been specified in XML , it was easy .. But i dont know how to do in runtime java class